# How do we see that the jump time of a Lévy process is exponentially distributed using the Markov property?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $X$ be a càdlàg Lévy process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ with $0\not\in\overline B$ and$^1$ $$\tau:=\inf\{t>0:\Delta X_t\in B\}.$$

> How do we show that $\tau$ has exponential distribution?

As usual, we "only" need to show that $$\operatorname P[\tau>s+t]=\operatorname P[\tau>s]\operatorname P[\tau>t]\tag1$$ for all $s,t\ge0$.

We know that $X$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $$\kappa_t(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[x+X_t\in B\right]\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal B(E)\text{ and }t\ge0.$$

We can show that $$\kappa(x,B):=\operatorname P[x+X\in B]\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}$$ with source $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and target $\left(E^{[0,\:\infty)},\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}\right)$. We can now define $$\operatorname P^{\mu}:=\mu\kappa$$ as the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Composition_of_kernels) of a probability measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and $\kappa$. In particular, we define $\operatorname P^x:=\operatorname P^{\delta_x}$, where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure at $x\in E$.

In the special case $E=\mathbb R$ and $B=\{1\}$, we can find the following proof in [Theorem 8.1 of *From Lévy-Type Processes to Parabolic SPDEs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WJHJDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22This+allows+us+to+consider+the+jumps+of+the+process+X%22&source=bl&ots=ha0dHk6aja&sig=ACfU3U1FMKPavoVv-YPu8x8Rv0235-9d-Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRr8Xl__bzAhVTSPEDHQzSBDYQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22This%20allows%20us%20to%20consider%20the%20jumps%20of%20the%20process%20X%22&f=false):

[image: Theorem 8.1]

Above, $\tau_1=\tau$ and $\operatorname P^{X_s}=\kappa(X_s,\;\cdot\;)$.

> How do the authors obtain the second and third equality above? And how do we generalize this to the setting of my question?

I don't know, but might it be easier to proof this by considering the coordinate process $(\pi_t)_{t\ge0}$ on $E^{[0,\:\infty)}$? For every probability measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$, this process is clearly a time-homogeneous Markov process with respect to $\operatorname P^\mu$ with transition kernel $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$.

Moreover, if we define $$\theta_s:E^{[0,\:\infty)}\to E^{[0,\:\infty)}\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto(x_{s+t})_{t\ge0}$$ for $s\ge0$, we've got $$\operatorname E\left[f\circ\theta_s\circ X\mid\mathcal F^X_s\right]=\int\kappa(X_s,{\rm d}y)f(y)\tag2$$ and, analogously, $$\operatorname E^{\mu}\left[f\circ\theta_s\mid\mathcal F^\pi_s\right]=\int\kappa(\pi_s,{\rm d}y)f(y)\;\;\;\text{for every probability measure }\mu$$ for all $s\ge0$ and bounded $\mathcal B(E)^{\otimes[0,\:\infty)}$-measurable $f:E^{[0,\:\infty)}\to\mathbb R$, where $\mathcal F^Y_t:=\sigma(Y_s,s\le t)$ for $t\ge0$ is the filtration generated by a process $Y$.

---

$^1$ As usual, $X_{t-}:=\lim_{s\to t-}X_s$ and $\Delta X_t:=X_t-X_{t-}$.

Answer (score 1):

The second equality is a consequence of  the strong Markov property.

The third is because of the spatial homogeneity of a Levy process: $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ under $\kappa(x,\cdot)$ has the same distribution as $x+X=(x+X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ under $\kappa(0,\cdot)$. Moreover, $X$ and $x+X$ have *identical* jumps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain how exactly the second equality follows from the strong Markov property? (And could you include your definition of the strong Markov property?)

Comment: I'd still be interested in this. Would be great if you could add an explanation.